# Getting Max date from the given two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with below structure and data.

```
id ean           Control_date qty
1  4046228081410 26.05.2017   568
2  4046228081410 05.06.2017   900
```

My expected result would be like below

```
2  4046228081410 05.06.2017   1468
```

To acheive this i am using the below query

```
 SELECT EAN,Control_date,SUM(Qty) AS Qty FROM mytable WHERE
(STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`,'%d.%m.%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('03.06.2017','%d.%m.%Y') 
OR 
STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y') <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('03.06.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
AND ean = 4046228081410
```

Here i need to sum up the qty where control date< today date and control date > today date and should be less than todaydate + 7 days . Here 2nd control date is 05.06.2017 and greater than today date and less than (03.05.2017 +7 days)
But always i am getting where contorl date is less than today date.

```
1  4046228081410 26.05.2017   1468
```

But i need data with control date **05.06.2017.**
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The two date conditions are redundant. If the date is less than 7 days from now, it is also less than today. Also, you need a group by (EAN?) and a max on control_date. See answer below

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Dates should be stored using the `date` data type, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really fix your date formats.  If you stored the value as a date, the query would simply be:

```
SELECT EAN, MAX(Control_date), SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM mytable
WHERE Control_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAYS AND
      Control_date >= CURDATE() AND
      ean = 4046228081410 
GROUP BY ean;
```

Note:  You can use a constant such as `'2017-06-03'` if you want a constant date.  However, your question specifically says the current date.

Just because you have bogus date formats stored in your data doesn't mean you have to use the same format in queries.  The expression `'2017-06-03'` (or `DATE('2017-06-03')`) is simpler than the more complex `STR_TO_DATE()` expression.

In your case, bite the bullet and output the date in a correct format, so you can do:

```
SELECT EAN, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y')), SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM mytable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y') < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAYS AND
      STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y') >= CURDATE() AND
      ean = 4046228081410 
GROUP BY ean;
```

Comment: now i am getting the max date but qty is not sum up, I am getting only 900 instead of 1468.

Comment: Hi ,any way i fixed the issue. Now its working like expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your SQL statement, and if you do not want today's date, then use less and greater

```
SELECT EAN,Control_date,SUM(Qty) AS Qty FROM mytable WHERE
(STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`,'%d.%m.%Y') **<** STR_TO_DATE('03.06.2017','%d.%m.%Y') 
OR 
STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y') **>** DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('03.06.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
AND ean = 4046228081410
```

Comment: This query is not sum up the qty and giving the lesser date

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues in your statement.

- Date conditions are redundant
- Need a MAX function on Control_date
- Need group by n EAN

  SELECT 
      EAN,
      max(Control_date) AS `control_date`,
      SUM(Qty) AS Qty 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE
      STR_TO_DATE(`Control_date`, '%d.%m.%Y') <= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('03.06.2017', '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
      AND
      ean = 4046228081410
  GROUP BY EAN